# Procedure for plotting domain $|2z+3|\gt 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I want to plot $|2z+3|\gt 4$. Firstly I plotted $|2z|\gt 4$, by taking it to be:$$|z|\gt 2$$
$$|x+iy|\gt 2$$

And this I am comfortable with, it is just everything greater than(in x or y values) than the line passing through $(0,2),(2,0)$.

Then I noted that, for example we can have $|z-2|\leq 1$ gives $|(x-2)+iy|\leq 1$ which is a circle centered at $(2,0)$, so this $-2$ translates my circle $2$ in the positive direction.

Now then I think that $|2z+3|\gt 4$ translates my line $3$ to the left. But then I tried just getting two points to be equal to $4$ to see where my line is, and I got the line passing through $(0,.5),(.5,0)$. Which aren't consistent.

How do I plot this domain? How should I think about these things?

Comment: Oh I think I see. First I translate it, and then I scale it?

Comment: Take $|2z|\gt 1$ and then $|z|\gt \frac12$?

Comment: The domain $|x+iy|\gt 2$ is quite unrelated to the line passing through $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$.

Comment: @Did I was thinking the area above that line(which would be an open set, where each polygonal line would be connected)

Comment: And this domain is quite unrelatd to this area as well.

Comment: @Did Sorry I made a mistake I know from ADG below. It should be the exterior region around a 1-sphere

Comment: Indeed -- and I suggest the more common name *circle*.

Comment: @Did thanks DID

Comment: @Did Thanks Did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\t}[1]{\text{#1}}
|z-(-3/2)|\ge 2\\
\t{matches with}\\
|z-z_0|\ge r\\\iff |(x+iy)-(x_0+iy_0)|\ge r\iff|(x-x_0)+i(y-y_0)|\ge r\\
\iff \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\ge r\iff (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\ge r^2
$$
Which is actually the exterior of circle with center $z_0$ and radius $r$, since distance from point is greater than r (think.think.)

Comment: Originally I thought it would be the exterior of a sphere, but I messed up whoops. So that would also be true of $|z|\gt 2$ right? exterior or a sphere of radius $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @möbius(i) sphere? I thought argand plane is 2D.(ii) Why are you squarerooting 2?

Comment: Sorry I did mean the 1-sphere of course. I meant if the question was just $|z|\gt 2$ I would have a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ right?

Comment: @möbius (i)there's difference between sphere and circle. and what is 1-sphere?

Comment: A 1-sphere is in english a circle

Comment: @möbius ok anyways

Comment: Shouldn't it be $r^2$ at the end?

Comment: @möbius no distance between the point would be r. I think you are confused with x^2+y^2=r^2.

Comment: Oh yes I am, thanks!